# Why "maybe-ubiquity" on default kernel command line?

Tags: server, grub2, kernel, ubiquity

On Ubuntu Server 18.04.03 LTS, fresh install, I wanted to do edit some kernel command line settings. In `/etc/default/grub`, I found the following set:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
```

I'm a Linux power user, but never really tried Ubuntu. So quick Google tells me that [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) is the Ubuntu installer. Why would a production server want to run the installer *maybe*?

Can I delete this entry? This is for a client's in-house server and I don't want to give anybody options to enter into an installer (accidentally). Furthermore, I have my own ways of getting into crippled systems. No need for an installer to help me.

Comment: The `maybe-ubiquity` boot parameter is for the desktop installer, and not for server. Perhaps something is overwriting the configuration, similar to this bug: /etc/default/grub.d/50-curtin-settings.cfg overwrites GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT ([1527664](https://bugs.launchpad.net/curtin/+bug/1527664))

Comment: This parameter is set after a vanilla Focal Fossa _server_ installation. I wonder why.

Comment: I just removed it cause I dont need the ubiquity installer. After removing this option from /etc/default/grub you need to run update-grub.

Comment: @user37165 I do not agree that the `maybe-ubiquity` parameter is present only on desktop installs. In my case I installed an Ubuntu 20.04 Server and the parameter is present. It seems it is a bug.

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK this param resides in the DEFAULT commandline after one has installed the system **from a LiveCD/DVD image**.

Ubiquity is an installer system Ubuntu uses on the live systems, there seems to be a bug that keeps this param also in the default commandline after installation.

I think it's safe to remove from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.