# Ubuntu 18.04 Server installation crashes when choosing partition

Tags: server, system-installation

The partition table on my machine is MBR and it looks like this:

sda4 (extended)

-sda5   - 1000MB `/boot` for Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 - ext4
-sda6   - 1000MB not used - ext4
-sda7   - 1000MB not used - ext4
-sda8   - 30GB `/`  for Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop - ext4
-sda9   - 30GB not used - ext4
-sda10 - 30GB not used - ext4
-sda11 - 12GB swap
-sda12 - 700GB `/home` - ext4

As you can see I have already successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop.
Partitions were made with GParted when installing Ubuntu 18.04 from a live USB. When I try to install Ubuntu Server 18.04, at the stage of selecting partitions, when I select the 9th partition, the installation process crashes every time.

[image]

This is how the report looks :

[image]

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @eyoung100 I have uploaded a photo of crash report, can you please check, I don't really know what that means.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the date shown in your screen capture would not support this, you might require the accepted solution in [Ubuntu 18.04 Installer crashes on Dell XPS 15 9560](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033179/ubuntu-18-04-installer-crashes-on-dell-xps-15-9560) (related: [Installer crashed when trying to install Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150797/installer-crashed-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu-18-04)).

I wouldn't think you are experiencing [Ubiquity install wizard crashes; cannot install ubuntu-MATE 18.04.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219958/ubiquity-install-wizard-crashes-cannot-install-ubuntu-mate-18-04-4).

**Related**:

1. [Why "maybe-ubiquity" on default kernel command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165399/why-maybe-ubiquity-on-default-kernel-command-line)
2. https://serverfault.com/questions/196625/can-ubuntu-server-be-installed-on-the-same-machine-running-ubuntu-desktop-if-ye

Comment: Thank you for the input but I'm trying to install server version and even if you can update ubiquity on server install (can you?), during the process of my installation there is no network connection. 
I can't see how these recommended answers would work with server install.

Comment: Instead I installed the Ubuntu 20.04 server legacy image and all works fine. 
You can find this image here  : http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/

Comment: @Tomas.R - It may have been that the newer version you installed has fixed the linked bug. What is the version of ubiquity in the server you installed?